# How can I avoid CR and LF when searching a file for a phrase that straddles two lines?

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to search an Html file for a list of words or phrases and write the file back out with added html tags around those words/phrases.  The rest of the file needs to remain as is.
I don't know how to get around the situation where a phrase is broken across two lines.  Can anyone help?  I'm  new to this so please be explicit in your answer.

Here's a piece of the input file: (the HTML p tags are on another line)

```
<p>
The thousand injuries of Fortunato I had borne as I best could, but
when he ventured upon insult, I vowed revenge.  You, who so well know
the nature of my soul, will not suppose, however, that I gave utterance
to a threat.  <i>At length</i> I would be avenged; this was a point definitely
```

and here is the code thus far:

```
    //get the table of words
    DataTable table = LibraryAccess.GetWords(titleID);

    using (StreamReader streamReader = File.OpenText(fileUploadPath))
    {
        inputString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        streamReader.Close();
        textCopy.Append(inputString);
    }

    if (inputString != null)
    {
        inputString = inputString.ToUpper();

        foreach (DataRow r in table.Rows)
        {
            searchWord = (r["Word"].ToString()).ToUpper();
            wordLength = searchWord.Length;
            foundIndex = inputString.IndexOf(searchWord);

            //if (foundIndex >= 0)
            //{

                //Use the Stringbuilder to modify the output file, e.g. add Bold tags
                //around the word/expression
            //}

            foundIndex = -1;

        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("input string is empty");
    }
  }
```

The Word I'm searching for is "gave utterance to"
In the source file, there is a CRLF after utterance, so the Indexof is not finding the Word.
I could easily replace the CRLF with a blank, but I need to put them back in the file when I write out the modified version.  I don't know how to preserve them.

Any thoughts on how to do this efficiently?  I will want to do for a variety of file lengths.  I was originally doing this with ReadLIne(), and would prefer that for memory reasons, but ran into the same problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about treating the HTML to a quick parse before trying to process it? Throwing it through [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) should help a lot with the job of extracting the text from the document.

Answer (score 0):

Generally what I would do in your situation is try to just get the plain text our of your HTML  and then do the search. This could probably be accomplished with the HtmlAgilityPack, but there is also [a CodeProject project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/HTML_to_Plain_Text.aspx) that does exactly this with a bunch of ugly RegEx searches. I haven't used it so I don't know if it will fix breaks in new lines in the HTML but it might be worth a shot.